# Как сгенерировать из приватного ключа публичный?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, bitcoin

Всё что я нашёл это:

```
 EC_KEY_set_private_key()
```

но он, вроде как, не генерирует публичный ключ, а только меняет приватный.

Comment: для RSA: [`EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA ()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA.html), не оно?

Comment: Мне желательно сделать это со структурой EC_KEY.

Comment: `EC_KEY` по идее это уже публичный ключ... тебе надо его вывести?

Comment: по идее EC_KEY это 'struct ec_key_st {
    const EC_KEY_METHOD *meth;
    ENGINE *engine;
    int version;
    EC_GROUP *group;
    EC_POINT *pub_key;
    BIGNUM *priv_key;
    unsigned int enc_flag;
    point_conversion_form_t conv_form;
    CRYPTO_REF_COUNT references;
    int flags;
    CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
    CRYPTO_RWLOCK *lock;
};'

Comment: И там есть отдельное поле для приватного ключа. p.s. И, да, я не знаю как тут выделять код, за помощь и в этом буду безмерно благодарен.

Comment: Нужно как-то поставить костыль, который спокойно впишется вместо `EC_KEY_generate_key(pkey)`, но с указанием конкретного значения для приватного ключа.